# What's the difference between casting a long to int versus using a bitwise AND in order to get the 4 least significant bytes?

Tags: c++, casting, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

I know that in order to get the 4 least significant bytes of a number of type `long` I can cast it to `int`/`unsigned int` or use a bitwise AND (`& 0xFFFFFFFF`).

[This](http://cpp.sh/6xnnv) code produces the following output:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  long n = 0x8899AABBCCDDEEFF;
  printf("0x%016lX\n", n);
  printf("0x%016X\n", (int)n);
  printf("0x%016X\n", (unsigned int)n);
  printf("0x%016lX\n", n & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

Output:

```
0x8899AABBCCDDEEFF
0x00000000CCDDEEFF
0x00000000CCDDEEFF
0x00000000CCDDEEFF
```

Does that mean that the two methods used are equivalent? If so, do they always produce the same output regardless of the platform/compiler?
Also, is there any catch or pitfall while casting to `unsigned int` rather than `int` for the purpose of this question?
Finally, why is the [output](http://cpp.sh/6qfh2) the same if you change the number `n` to be an `unsigned long` instead?

Comment: I believe that `long` can be 16 bits on some platforms, and I know for a fact that `int` can be 16 bits on some platforms... So it's definitely platform-dependent.

Comment: In short, the two operations are equivalent if and only if `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT == 32` on the given platform.

Comment: Hi Gilgames. Welcome to Stack Overflow. As others have pointed out, the size of int and long is different in different platforms. Now, I'd recommend you that in future questions you put the code for all your questions here. I was not able to open the link you specified in "output", so I'm not able to answer all your questions

Comment: @goodvibration `long` is _at least_ 32-bit - not 16.  `int` is _at least_ 16-bit.

Comment: The size of a `long` is platform-dependent. [The C++ standard only specifies minimum sizes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Answer (score 1):

The methods are definitely different.

According to integral conversion rules (cf, for example, [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.integral) online c++11 standard), a conversion (e.g. through an explicit cast) from one integral type to another depends on whether the destination type is signed or unsigned. If the destination type is unsigned, one can rely on a "modulo 2n" truncation, whereas with signed destination types one could tap into implementation defined behaviour:

> **4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral]**
>
> 2 If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the
>   least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (**modulo 2n
>   where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type**). [
>   Note: In a two's complement representation, this conversion is
>   conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no
>   truncation).  — end note ]
>
> 3 If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width);
>   **otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.**

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, as others have pointed out, the size of int and long is dependent on the platform, so the methods are not equivalent. In [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), check that the types say "**at least** XX bits in size"

For the second question, it comes down to this: long and int are signed, meaning that one bit is reserved for sign (take a look also to [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). If you were the compiler, what can you do with negative values (especially the long ones)? As Stepahn Lechner mentioned, this is implementation defined (that is, is up to the compiler).

Finally, in the spirit of "your code must do what it says it does", the best thing to do if you need to do masks is to use masks (and, if you use masks, use unsigned types). Don't try to use cleaver answers. Believe me, they always bite you in the rear. I've dealt with a lot of legacy code to know that by heart.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between casting a long to int versus using a bitwise AND in order to get the 4 least significant bytes?

Type.  Casting makes the value an `int`.  And'ing does not change the type.

Range.  Depending on `int,long` range, a cast may not change the value at all.

IDB and UB. *implementation defined behavior* and *undefined behavior* are present with mixing signed-ness.

To "get" the 4 LSBytes, use `& 0xFFFFFFFFu` or cast to `uint32_t`.

---

OP's question is unnecessarily convoluted.

`long n = 0x8899AABBCCDDEEFF;` --> Converting a value outside the range of a *signed integer type* is *implementation-defined*.

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.
>   C11 §6.3.1.3 3

`printf("0x%016lX\n", n);` --> Printing a `long` with a `"%lX"` outside the the common range  of `long/unsigned long` is *undefined behavior*.

---

Let's go forward with `unsigned long`:

```
  unsigned long n = 0x8899AABBCCDDEEFF;  // no problem,
  printf("0x%016lX\n", n);               // no problem,
  printf("0x%016X\n", (int)n);           // problem, C11 6.3.1.3 3
  printf("0x%016X\n", (unsigned int)n);  // no problem,
  printf("0x%016lX\n", n & 0xFFFFFFFF);  // no problem,
```

The "no problem" are OK even is `unsigned long` is 32-bit or 64-bit.  The output will differ, yet is OK.

Recall that `int,long` are not always 32,64 bit.  (16,32), (32,32), (32,64) are common.

`int` is *at least* 16 bit.
`long` is *at least* that of `int` and *at least* 32 bit.

---